# Save text to repository without creating a file?

Tags: git, repository

Is there any way to save a echo output to repository without creating a file for it?
With creating a file the command would look like this:

echo "hello world" > readme.txt | git add readme.txt

i want to add "hello world" to the repository without creating the readme.txt file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [ElpieKay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63951899/1256452) shows you how to put an object in the repository, but note that unless you save its ID somewhere reachable from a reference name, Git may discard it later. If you don't save it as a file-in-a-commit, you'll have to save it some other way; saving it as a file-in-a-commit is by far the *easiest* way to make it reachable, as all the usual tools will then work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "hello world" | git hash-object -w --stdin
```

> git-hash-object - Compute object ID and optionally creates a blob from
> a file

Reference: [git hash-object](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-hash-object)

`-w`

Actually write the object into the object database.

`--stdin`

Read the object from standard input instead of from a file.

The command returns the SHA1(the object ID) of the blob object. You can use `git show <SHA1>` to print its content.

As @torek pointed out in the comment, the object might get discarded. To save it, you can create a tag to refer to it, by `git tag <tagname> <SHA1>`. Later, you can use the tag instead of the SHA1.

Comment: See also [commit 1d76e69](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d76e69212102c3373b552186590b76d6ad8d84c) for a `git hash-object` doc update.